# How to update RxJs timer in child component concurrently?

Tags: angular, rxjs, timer

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cjegkj?file=src/app/timer/timer.component.ts

I have parent element, where you can add timer component on button click.
Component has function, which starts timer, but if i add more than 1 timer, they update not at the same time. So if first timer showed 19:48:20, the second would be 19:48:19

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.startTimer();
  }

  startTimer(): void {
    timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return new Date();
      })
    ).subscribe((time) => {
      this.time = time;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your Stackblitz is correct, they update every second from the start and the beginning is not the same!

Comment: But what should i do to update all timers at one time ? To be 19:48:20, 19:48:20

Comment: try this: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1nteia?file=src/app/timer/timer.component.ts

I created a service that provided in root. that service holds a variable of type observable when subscribed that value is shared with the operator shareReplay

Comment: Yes, that's what i want, thanks!